# express routes with es6 classes : Cannot create property 'next' on string '/'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I am trying to implement routes with classes in my express js application

controller

```
class User {

    constructor (){
        this.username = 'me';

    }

    getUsername(req,res){

        res.json({
            'name':this.name
        });

    }
}

export default User;
```

In my routes

```
import express from 'express'
import User from './controller'

const router = express.Router();
const user   = new User();

router('/',user.getUsername.bind(user));

export default UserRoute
```

But I got this error

> req.next = next;
>              ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot create property 'next' on string '/'
>       at Function.handle (/var/accubits-workspace/express-es6/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:160:12)

Comment: Also, it should be `this.username` instead of `this.name` in your `getUsername` method, but I'm guessing that's a typo. Also noticed there's no `UserRoute` variable in your file. Did you mean `export default router`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are not using any method on the router object, you need something like `get` , `post`, `put` , `delete` or other http/https verbs or `use` for creating middleware.

for example

```
router.VERB("/", ...);
```

Answer (score -1):

router.(use HTTP method like(get,post...))('/',user.getUsername.bind(user));

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).